# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in Form and Multi Image upload in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

The Form upload and the product image as featured image and other other images using the store function of laravel

```
use App\Productimage;
use App\Products; 
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $featured = $request->featured_image->store('products_featured');
    $product = Products::create([       //uploading successfully
    'name'=>$request->name,
    'featured_image' => $featured,
    ]);
             foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {   //error
        $filename = $photo->store('product_images');
        Productimage::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'image_name' => $filename,
        ]);
    }
    return back();
}
```

Comment: try to print request body. maybe $request->photos doesn't have an image array.

Comment: Please dd($request->photos); before the foreach line and paste it to your post

Comment: Hi @AkashKumarVerma,   dd($request->photos) is null

Comment: @Naren check my answer

Comment: What's your question? Is there any bug? What have you tried to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `$request->photos` is an array and your form is a `multipart/form-data`.
You need to send your files from your blade (or wherever your are sending them from) in `photos[]`, e.g.

```
<input type="file" name="photos[]"/>
```

P.S - In your controller method, you should access `$request->photos` like this `$request->file('photos')`. - This is not the cause of your error but if you don't do this, you'll get a JSON object instead of file content.

Answer (score 0):

you form should have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and input type file is `array`

```php
   foreach ($request->file('photos') as $photo) {   //error
            $filename = $photo->store('product_images');
            Productimage::create([
                'product_id' => $product->id,
                'image_name' => $filename,
            ]);
        }
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="photos[]"/>
```