# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() using laravel 7

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload images but unfortunately, I am getting errors when submitting the form please help me how can resolve that?

please check the error https://flareapp.io/share/KPgXYVg7

uploader desgin
https://ibb.co/WpxS0Yk

**controller**

```
   public function store(Request $request)
     {
        // dd($request->all());
    
    foreach ($request->file('image') as $key => $value) {
      $extension = $value->getClientOriginalExtension();
      $image[$key] = $value->getFilename() . '.' . $extension;

      Storage::disk('yourstitchart')->put($value->getFilename() . '.' . $extension, File::get($value));
    }

    $input = $request->except("_token");

    $input['user_id'] = Auth::user()->id;
    $input['image'] =  $image;
    Digitizingorder::create($input);
    
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

**HTML view**

**script**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  
    $("#upload_files").change(function (e) {
        // readURL(this);

        var jamo = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
        $('#upload-preview').attr('src', jamo);

        var imgpath = document.getElementById('upload_files');
        if (!imgpath.value == "") {
            var img = imgpath.files[0].size;
            var imgsize = img / 1024;
            var imgsizeN = imgsize.toFixed(2);
        }

        var fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
        $('.file_list').append(`
        <p class="image_data" src="${jamo}"> ${imgsizeN} kb / ${fileName} </p>
            <input type="text"  name="image[]" value="${fileName}" >
        
        `);

        var file = (e.srcElement || e.target).files[0];
        console.log(file);
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.image_data', function () {
        var getSrc = $(this).attr('src');
        $('#upload-preview').attr('src', getSrc);
    });
});
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the error messages you are facing (in text form, not as a screen shot, and not on any external site!), and your attempts to resolve these errors

Comment: I may be wrong, but to me, it look more like you get the filename than the actual images in your request.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60222127/invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach-in-form-and-multi-image-upload-in-larave

Comment: Make sure that you are getting image in request. 
>if($reqeust->has('image')){}

Comment: yes, I am  getting images in this request. please check https://flareapp.io/share/353ND097#F48

Comment: Has we said, you're sending the **filename** not the actual image `<input type="text"  name="image[]" value="${fileName}" >`